# DNS server cannot be found

Tags: android, dns

I created a simple examples and run it in emulator, every time where the emulator prepare to running it gives me a warning:

> DNS server not found

and emulator starts normally. What does this mean and what this effect on my application? Why does android need a DNS server?

Answer (score 2):

Do this:

1. Open Eclipse
2. Window>Preferences>Android>
3. Click Launch
4. I hope you see the Default emulator options
5. Then put the values that box  -dns-server 8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a LAN connection to internet and you have a static DNS set there, the emulator might have a problem with that, if you are using wireless for example.

The Android emulator is using the DNS server to connect to internet so you can access different features from the internet within it.

Check your LAN configuration. If you are using wireless connection and you have LAN DNS server set, just remove it from LAN, and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

I've had issues with DNS resolution on the emulator, which I am usually able to fix by killing and restarting the emulator.

Answer (score -1):

```
windows->preferences->android->launch->
```

paste: to default emulator option as:

```
-dns-server 8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4
```

Comment: How is this different from [Silambarasan Thangaraj's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13596915/1816580)? There is no need for duplication. You can delete your answer.