# Connecting Wamp server with Android

Tags: android, wamp

Eclipse is showing a warning,

> "NO DNS SERVERS FOUND".

I am using `10.0.2.2` in HttpClient class in Java file.

I have alredy added Internet Permission in Manifest.xml file.

In My Java Program :

```
url = "http://10.0.2.2/SERVERFOLDER/FORM.php";
```

If my laptop is online , 10.0.2.2 is working in emulator browser and also in laptop browser its working. Eclipse android is also working, but if my laptop is not connected with internet eclipse console showing warning

> no dns server found

, and android program is not working.

Answer (score 0):

You code
`url = "http : // 10.0.2.2 / SERVERFOLDER/FORM.php";`
should not contain spaces.

As for the DNS error, see the top answer here: [DNS server cannot be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7497045/dns-server-connont-be-found)

Answer (score 0):

try to connect your phone to laptop over wireless, after this internet is not required, both devices will be in the same network

Answer (score 0):

Because to acess local host or 10.0.2.2 from emulator the both PC and android device should be connected on the same wireless network.